# Azure Data Factory (v2) - Custom activity pipeline stuck in state -Permissions issue

Tags: azure, azure-batch, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I am new to ADF v2. I am trying to do a POC with a custom activity component. I want to run a console application within a pool inside batch service. After configuring everything, the pipeline is stuck in "In Progress" state forever and no error messages are coming up. Below are the important bits of the ADF Pieline:

**ADF Pipeline Custom Task**

- Connection to batch link service is successful
  [image]
- Connection to linked resource service is successful
  [image]
- The console application exe and dlls are placed in the linked storage account
  [image]
- After triggering the pipeline, jobs are created within batch service
  [image]

[image]

- Pool config
  [image]

[image]

- Access issue
  [image]
- In the storage account where exe and DLLS associated with storage account is kept, some jsons are created, but after the job fail, they dissappear
  [image]
- The code for my .net core console application is

  using System;

  namespace HelloADF
  {
  class Program
  {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
  }
  }
  }

Comment: What does your pool configuration look like? Do you have any nodes defined? The JSON files in the folder are submitted by ADF and will be replaced with standard out and err TXT files when the job is complete.

Comment: The problem is that the job does not complete. I do accept though that I didnt had any nodes which I have now

I have updated the question with Pool config as well. Its a basic_a1 windows server.

Problem is still the same after adding a node

Comment: @JoelCochran - After looking at ur update, I changed the pool config. I get a different error and I have updated the issue but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Two thoughts - I only use low-priority nodes, not dedicated nodes (not sure what the cost impact of dedicated might be). The error message is clearly about Blob access permissions, so maybe recheck your SAS settings?